# Is there a way to block keyboard input without any packages?

Tags: python

I made a function that types out messages:

```
import time
import sys

def log(message, color=colors['white'], wait=0.03, delay=0.2, newline=True):
  for i in message:
    time.sleep(delay if i == '\n' else wait)
    sys.stdout.write(color + i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(delay)
  sys.stdout.write('\n' if newline else ' ')
```

It works perfectly.
But if the user touches a key, it would be outputted to the console, disrupting the message being typed.

Like if it was supposed to type out "monster" and the user types "s" before it finished, the output would be like "monstesr", not what it meant to type out.

Does anyone know a way of restricting the keyboard input? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are going to want a third-party library for this. You should be prepared to do some [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), which might involve asking on an actual *discussion forum* such as Reddit or Quora. A question like this is off topic here, because it is a bit open-ended (if you want this behaviour, you are probably going to end up wanting a lot of other related things; and there are a few conceivable ways that it would work on a technical level), and because we do not recommend tools or libraries here (too subjective).

Comment: Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for more guidance on appropriate question scope for Stack Overflow.